# Relationship data to view - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Having a Problem to output a relationship data to view. 
Error message is: "Trying to get property of non-object View".

For explanation all Task depend to a job. 
So Task belongsTo Job and Job hasMany tasks. 
I have all Relationships in my Models and test it in Tinker everything works.

In my view I Output every Task name and the job name

```
  @foreach ($tasks as $task)
    <div class="list-item">
         <span class="item-name">{{ $task->job->name }}
         <span class="item-name">{{ $task->name}} </span>
     </div>
  @endforeach
```

The index function of my TaskController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $label = Label::all();
    $user = User::all();
    $task = Task::orderBy('duedate')->get();
    $team = Team::all();
    $customer = Customer::all();
    $status = Status::all();
    $job = Job::all();
    return view('tasks.index')->with([
        'tasks' => $task,
        'teams' => $team,
        'customers' => $customer,
        'labels' => $label,
        'users' => $user,
        'jobs' => $job,
        'statuses' => $status,
    ]);
}
```

Table schema / output from tinker

```
 id: 1,
 assigned_user_id: 1,
 team_id: 4,
 name: "Label many to many ",
 duration: 2,
 created_at: "2016-06-16 14:50:57",
 updated_at: "2016-07-05 09:10:34",
 job_id: 1,
 duedate: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
 status_id: 3,
 job: App\Job {#702
   id: 1,
   name: "quia",
   jobnumber: "8076",
   customer_id: 2,
   status_id: 0,
   created_at: null,
   updated_at: null,
 },
 user: null,
```

Relationships

**Job Model **

```
class Job extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name', 'jobnumber', 'customer_id', 'status_id'];

/**
 * Get all Task for Job
 */
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

**Task model**

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Please share your table schema and relationship code

Comment: If a `Job` has multiples `Task`, then the relationship should be called `tasks` and not `task`. It probably won't solve the issue tho.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to your answer:

> *In the DB some Task entries had an job_id to an none exisiting Job*

You can use `has` method to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. see doc for [querying relationship absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

```
$task=Task::orderBy('duedate')->has('job')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind o f error occurs when you are trying to print a model value that doesn't exists. Try to print using `{{isset($task->job->name)?$task->job->name:'Task without Job'}}` and check what it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load the "job" relationship on `$task` before trying to access it's values :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $label = Label::all();
    $user = User::all();
    $task = Task::with('job')->orderBy('duedate')->get(); // loading the relationship
    $team = Team::all();
    $customer = Customer::all();
    $status = Status::all();
    $job = Job::all();
    return view('tasks.index')->with([
        'tasks' => $task,
        'teams' => $team,
        'customers' => $customer,
        'labels' => $label,
        'users' => $user,
        'jobs' => $job,
        'statuses' => $status,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.

Comment: Then I get an 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::jobs()

Comment: Thanks, but getting still get the "Trying to get property of non-object" Error. 
:(

Comment: "ErrorException in aae6d87ae7f8586ad5afa38cfe88fb5c0cdbb89f.php line 18:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users.../resources/views/tasks/index.blade.php)
in aae6d87ae7f8586ad5afa38cfe88fb5c0cdbb89f.php line 18
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '0') in PhpEngine.php line 44..."

Comment: Add the following error and the code at line 18 in `aae6d87ae7f8586ad5afa38cfe88fb5c0cdbb89f.php` in your OP please.

Comment: @AntoineB we can access the relationship as if it were a property, pre loading relationship before accessing is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

In the DB some Task entries had an job_id to an none exisiting Job, thats it.